# Optimizing iterating script on Google Script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm attempting to make this script run faster.

```
function refreshWeeklyReport() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var weeklyReportSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Weekly Report");

  var oneDayAgoReport = initializeDaysAgoReportObject(3,1,1);
  var twoDaysAgoReport = initializeDaysAgoReportObject(11,1,2);
  var threeDaysAgoReport = initializeDaysAgoReportObject(19,1,3);
  var fourDaysAgoReport = initializeDaysAgoReportObject(27,1,4);
  var fiveDaysAgoReport = initializeDaysAgoReportObject(35,1,5);
  var sixDaysAgoReport = initializeDaysAgoReportObject(43,1,6);
  var sevenDaysAgoReport = initializeDaysAgoReportObject(51,1,7);

  var reports = [oneDayAgoReport, twoDaysAgoReport, threeDaysAgoReport, fourDaysAgoReport, fiveDaysAgoReport, sixDaysAgoReport, sevenDaysAgoReport];

  reports.forEach(function(report) {
    // Assign random colors
    var colorDiff = randomColor(150);
    var r = colorDiff.r;
    var g = colorDiff.g;
    var b = colorDiff.b;
    var summary = getSumsForDates(report.date, addDays(report.date,1), true, r,g,b, false);
    Logger.log('Summary' + JSON.stringify(summary));
    Logger.log('Report' + JSON.stringify(report));
    report.linearFeetCell.setValue(summary.linearFeet);
    report.piecesCell.setValue(summary.pieces);
    report.boardFootageCell.setValue(summary.boardFootage);
    report.trussesCell.setValue(summary.trusses);
    report.salesDollarsCell.setValue(summary.salesDollars);
    report.setupsCell.setValue(summary.setups);
    // Randomize colors here
    report.dayCell.setBackgroundRGB(r, g, b);

  });
}
```

And here's the other function that's being called:

```
function initializeDaysAgoReportObject(startRow, startColumn, numberOfDaysAgo)
{
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var weeklyReportSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Weekly Report");

  var daysAgoReport = {}; // Creates an object

  // Variables
  daysAgoReport.startRow = startRow;
  daysAgoReport.startColumn = startColumn;
  daysAgoReport.date = minusDays(new Date(), numberOfDaysAgo);
  daysAgoReport.date.setHours(0);
  daysAgoReport.day = days[daysAgoReport.date.getDay()];
  daysAgoReport.dateCell = weeklyReportSheet.getRange(startRow,startColumn + 1);
  daysAgoReport.dayCell = weeklyReportSheet.getRange(startRow,startColumn);

  daysAgoReport.linearFeetCell = weeklyReportSheet.getRange(startRow+1,startColumn+1);
  daysAgoReport.piecesCell = weeklyReportSheet.getRange(startRow+3,startColumn+1);
  daysAgoReport.boardFootageCell = weeklyReportSheet.getRange(startRow+5,startColumn+1);
  daysAgoReport.trussesCell = weeklyReportSheet.getRange(startRow+1,startColumn+7);
  daysAgoReport.salesDollarsCell = weeklyReportSheet.getRange(startRow+1,startColumn+4);
  daysAgoReport.setupsCell = weeklyReportSheet.getRange(startRow+2,startColumn+7);

  daysAgoReport.nonOverTimeLaborCostCell = weeklyReportSheet.getRange(startRow+4,startColumn+4);
  daysAgoReport.overTimePremiumCostCell = weeklyReportSheet.getRange(startRow+6,startColumn+4);

  daysAgoReport.nonOverTimeLaborHoursCell = weeklyReportSheet.getRange(startRow+2,startColumn+10);
  daysAgoReport.overTimeLaborHoursCell = weeklyReportSheet.getRange(startRow+4,startColumn+10);

  var displayDate = addDays(daysAgoReport.date,1);
  daysAgoReport.dayCell.setValue(daysAgoReport.day);
  daysAgoReport.dateCell.setValue(displayDate);

  //set labor cells
  var laborData = getTotalsFromLabor(daysAgoReport.date);

  daysAgoReport.nonOverTimeLaborCostCell.setValue(laborData.regularLaborCost);
  daysAgoReport.overTimePremiumCostCell.setValue(laborData.overTimePremium);

  daysAgoReport.nonOverTimeLaborHoursCell.setValue(laborData.regularHours);
  daysAgoReport.overTimeLaborHoursCell.setValue(laborData.overtimeHours);

  return daysAgoReport;
}
```

This function does the calculations:

```
function getSumsForDates(dateStart, dateEnd, highlightActiveRows, r,g,b, clearInActiveRows)
{
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var reportSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Custom Report");
  var summary = {};
  summary.linearFeet = 0;
  summary.pieces = 0;
  summary.boardFootage =0;
  summary.trusses = 0;
  summary.salesDollars = 0;
  summary.setups = 0;

  var summaryOffset = 15;
  // If Customeer Report data exceeds 3000, TypeError will occur.
  var dateColumn = reportSheet.getRange(summaryOffset,17,3000,1); 
  var values = dateColumn.getValues(); // get all data in one call
  var currentRow = 0;

  while ( values[currentRow][0] != "" ) {
    var dateBuilt = new Date(values[currentRow][0]); 
    var afterStart = dateBuilt.getTime() >= dateStart.getTime();
    var beforeEnd = dateBuilt.getTime() <= dateEnd.getTime()
    var currentRange = reportSheet.getRange(currentRow + summaryOffset,1,1,17)
    var currentValues = currentRange.getValues();
    if( afterStart && beforeEnd )
    {
      var linearFeet = currentValues[0][6];
      var pieces = currentValues[0][9];
      var boardFootage = currentValues[0][13];
      var trusses = currentValues[0][1];
      var salesDollars = currentValues[0][15];

      summary.linearFeet += linearFeet;
      summary.pieces += pieces;
      summary.boardFootage += boardFootage;
      summary.trusses += trusses;
      summary.salesDollars += salesDollars;
      summary.setups++

        if(highlightActiveRows)
        {
          currentRange.setBackgroundRGB(r,g,b);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        if(clearInActiveRows)
        {
          currentRange.setBackgroundRGB(255,255,255);
        }
    }
    currentRow++;
  }

  return summary;
}
```

I believe that most of the optimization should happen in the getSumsForDates function, as it's doing all  the reading and calculating. Instead of iterating through each line, is there a faster way of doing this?

Comment: You've got `var currentValues = currentRange.getValues();` inside a loop of up to 3000 rows. `getValues` is a reasonably costly command. I'd put `getDataRange().getValues()` [(Doc reference)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getdatarange) **before** the `while` (I might keep `dateColumn.getValues()` to simplify things) and then  re-work how you calculate `currentValues`. Overall this ought to save a LOT of time. BTW, I was interested in your line "// If Customeer Report data exceeds 3000, TypeError will occur." - what's that about?